# Объединение полей сводной таблицы

Tags: excel

Нужно верификацию, отметки верификации и телефонные звонки объединить в одно поле. Подскажите алгоритм.

[image: поля сводной таблицы]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выделил ячейки "верификация" и "отметки верификации" , нажал пкм и выбрал группировку. После чего в строке (поля сводной таблицы) появляется новая строка. Удаляем изначальную и повторяем процедуру с телефонными звонками.